# ¿Cuál sería una buena traducción para "fat finger"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, expresiones, solicitud-de-modismo, jerga-internet

"Fat finger", o "fat-finger" es una expresión relativamente común en inglés para referirse a la situación en la que se pulsa una tecla equivocada que está cerca de la que se quería pulsar. En inglés, se puede usar [como verbo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/fat-finger-meaning):

> I fat-fingered her email address and sent my message to the wrong person

o como adjetivo ([fat-fingered](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/fat-fingered)):

> A fat-fingered trader brought chaos to the market.

No se me ocurre una expresión en español con este significado, aparte de las obvias "teclear mal" o "cometer un error al teclear" (que no expresan la idea de que las teclas están cerca).

¿Hay alguna expresión en español con este significado? Me interesan tanto el significado verbal ("*He fat-fingered my email address*") como el adjetival ("*He is a fat-fingered person*", o alternativamente "*he has fat fingers*").

Comment: Lo único ligeramente coloquial que se parece a esto y que recuerde es “meter mal el dedo” pero no tiene la versatilidad del inglés. “Manos de manteca” es una expresión figurativa similar pero es más bien para referirse a torpeza al agarrar cosas. “Pifiarle a las teclas” también es común.

Comment: En Argentina, muchos usamos "tener los dedos mochos", en referencia al significado de "mocho" en el diccionario: *5. m. Remate grueso y romo de un instrumento o utensilio largo, como la culata de un arma de fuego.*

Comment: Una palabra muy usada es “manazas”, aunque tiene un significado más general que el de ser torpe al teclear. Funciona bien como sustantivo y adjetivo, pero no hay forma de usarlo como verbo.

Comment: A mí lo que más me viene a la cabeza es el _dedazo_. No es expresión, pero se entiende rápidamente y es traducción casi literal. La he oído bastante

Answer (score 3):

Cuando esto me pasaba a mi solía decir que era un error "por tener **manitas de cerdo**" (o pezuñas de cerdo). El símil (intentar escribir código o un email cuando tienes pezuñitas en lugar de deditos) es claro.

El problema, como sucede a veces en este tipo de preguntas, es que el español no tiene la flexibilidad del inglés para transformar un nombre en un verbo de manera casi automática.

En el sentido adjetival que plantea la pregunta ("He is a fat-fingered person", o alternativamente "he has fat fingers") yo sustituiría el "ser" por el "tener" en la traducción, como en el segundo ejemplo.

> Tiene **manitas de cerdo** y se suele equivocar bastante el teclear

Aunque también podrías denominar a alguien "manitas de cerdo".

> Diego **es** un *manitas de cerdo*. Suele cometer muchos errores al teclado

Para el sentido adjetival, necesitaría el circunloquio

> Ese *bug* se debió a un error de *manitas de cerdo*. Tecleé mal el valor de esa variable

> Cometí un error de *manitas de cerdo* con la dirección de email

> Hice un "manitas de cerdo" y he enviado este email a la dirección equivocada.

En unos casos la expresión puede resultar un tanto cómica, pero en otros despectiva

> A *fat-fingered* trader brought chaos to the market > Un agente de bolsa con *manitas de cerdo* causó el caos en los mercados (o la bolsa)

Comment: Lo de "meter la pezuña" en esos casos lo he dicho (y escuchado) más de una vez, con esa misma idea de que alguien con pezuñas será obviamente más torpe que alguien con dedos.

Answer (score 2):

Cuando se usaban máquinas de escribir la gente de los periódicos cuando se presentaban  errores tipográficos decían

> fue el diablillo del teclado

Answer (score 1):

No tenemos algo prestablecido creo.

Yo justificaría la torpeza de mi tipeo disculpándome con que  `se me cruzaron los dedos de orangután` al escribir

Posiblemente más de uno me entienda y se ría.